# AngularJS multiple functions in service

Tags: angularjs

I have the following service in my AngularJS app, but I am getting error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: NewContactDataProvider <- NewContactData
```

my NewContactData code:

```
myApp.factory('NewContactData', function($http,$log, $q) {
 return {    
   saveContact: function(contact){
   } 
   getContacts: function(){

   }      
 }; 
});
```

Can someone please point to me what I am doing wrong in it? I just defined a new function getContacts that's all.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a missing comma in your code :) try:

```
myApp.factory('NewContactData', function($http,$log, $q) {
 return {    
   saveContact: function(contact){
   }, 
   getContacts: function(){

   }      
 }; 
});
```

Comment: @c0bra it takes 7 mins for anyone asking a question to get it accepted, this is SO rules, you might want to check them out :)